How did Maeda continue to operate in post-war Gyeongseong?
In the second season of Gyeongseong Creature, Maeda Yukiko is revealed not only to have remained in Korea after the defeat of Imperial Japan, but to have plotted revenge against Jang Tae-sang:

She has at least a dozen soldiers attack him at a bar in broad daylight, and go to his pawn shop to kill his employees at the same time. Not only was she seen entering the bar, but she seems to have left (again, in broad daylight and in public view) with the same black-clad assassins who had just been ransacking and murdering in the pawn shop.

Of course, Maeda and her colleagues had previously gotten away with arguably equally terrible things in public, during the period during which Japan controlled Korea, but this would have been two years afterward, putting it firmly during the United States Army Military Government in Korea, when even being Japanese was a cause for suspicion, let alone being the spouse of the former Japanese military police chief for Gyeongseong, to say nothing of attacking and (apparently) murdering one of the city's most prominent citizens.
How did Maeda not only manage to remain in Korea during the post-war period, but carry out such actions with impunity?
